# How would one efficiently call an API in React many times and assign the contents to an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have two APIs. One API returns every item  in a list with the list ID as the parameter:

```
    MyApiHelper.getItemsByListId(this.props.selectedListId, newPageNumber, pageSize, sort).then(
      (result) => {
        if (!_.isNil(result)){
          this.setState({
            items: result.content,
            pageInfo: result.pageInfo,
            loading: false
          });
          for (const element of result.content) {
            this.getItemAvailability(element.id);
          }
        }
      }
```

Another API checks how many of each item are available, with each item ID as the parameter.

```
  getItemAvailability(itemId){
    MyApiHelper.getItemAvailability(ItemId).then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          itemAvailability: [...this.state.itemAvailability, result]
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        this._handleError(error, EpsErrorHandler,
          'add_external_comment_error_title', 'add_external_comment_error_message');
      });
  }
```

My question is, is there a better way to design `getItemAvailability(itemId)` to make the calls/state update more efficient? The end result I require is an array of availability in the state variable `itemAvailability`.

Comment: the best thing would be if you can send a list of itemIds to the api, and it can send you a normalized array with all available items for each itemId (rather than sending each itemId individually). Another option could be to loop through all the itemIds and create promises for each, then do a `Promise.all(yourPromiseArray).then`

Comment: May you change the backend code or you just have this APIs?

Comment: @duxfox-- altering the API would be ideal and would be the long term solution, but would be a stretch for the sprint time remaining.

Comment: @Margon long term yes, they will be redone. But ideally we wouldn't for this quick change.

Comment: @duxfox-- I like the Promise.all. Shall try it/

Comment: In the short term, just use a promise.all as @duxfox said, it's the best options for short term